# Mounting/unmounting TrueCrypt volumes without opening the program

Tags: truecrypt

I used the advice given at the end of [this article](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/11/encrypt-folders-partitions-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelotpart-ii/)
to mount a TrueCrypt volume by double-clicking it. But I can't unmount it without opening TrueCrypt (`umount: /media/truecrypt1 is not in the fstab (and you are not root)`) so being able to mount it without opening the program is kind of a moot achievement. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Suggestion One**

You can use a terminal to unmount it.

For example, I have an encrypted file named `enc1` that is on `/home/desgua/Dropbox/`, so to mount it I should use:

`truecrypt --mount /home/desgua/Dropbox/enc1 /mnt/mymountpoint/`

And to unmount:

`truecrypt -d /home/desgua/Dropbox/enc1`

or simple:

`truecrypt -d`  (which should unmount every truecrypted mounted files)

.

**Suggestion Two**

Also you can create a launcher to unmount it:

1) Paste this at terminal: `gedit ~/Desktop/unmounttruecrypt.desktop`,

2) Then paste this into the file and save:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Unmount Truecrypt
Comment=Unmount all mounted Truecrypt files
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"truecrypt -d ; exit; exec bash\""
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/actions/48/player_eject.svg
Categories=Application;Accessories;
```

3) Now look at your desktop and drag the file to the Launcher.

.

**Suggestion Three**

Make a script to unmount it for you:

1) Paste this at terminal: `gedit ~/Desktop/utscript`,

2) Then paste this into the file and save:

```
#!/bin/bash
mnt=$(mountpoint /mnt/mymountpoint/) # See suggestion One

if [[ $mnt == "/mnt/mymountpoint/ is a mountpoint" ]]; then

    truecrypt -d /home/desgua/Dropbox/enc1 | zenity --progress --percentage=40 --auto-close --title="Unmounting" --text="I am umounting it now."
    sleep 2 | zenity --progress --percentage=100 --auto-close --title="Done!" --text="Done unmounting!" 
    else

    sleep 2 | zenity --progress --percentage=100 --auto-close --title="Already done!" --text="It is unmounted already!" 

    fi

exit 0
```

4) Paste this at terminal: `chmod +x ~/Desktop/utscript`

Answer (score 3):

try adding it to the /etc/fstab. That worked for me.

```
/dev/mapper/truecrypt1 /media/truecrypt1  auto   rw,user 0      0
```

Comment: Haven't tested it since I use LUKS, but it seems legit.

Comment: I added the line to fstab. I now get this error: `umount: only root can unmount /dev/mapper/truecrypt1 from /media/truecrypt1` which is weird since I did enter the root PW (same as admin) before I could mount the volume.

Comment: If you mount it as root only root can unmount it. Try to mount and unmount it as normal user.

Comment: Had a look into the `user` option  again ... "Only the user that mounted a filesystem can unmount it again. If any user should be able to unmount, then use users instead of user in the fstab line. " Maybe it works better with the `users` option for you.

Comment: `/dev/mapper/truecrypt1 /media/truecrypt1  auto   rw,users 0      0` (users with an S) didn't help. I still need to enter admin pw upon mounting/unmounting.

Comment: OK, I tried again. When I mount the volume the first time via the GUI I need to enter the Admin pwd. Then I can mount and unmount the volume via command line without pwd.



I had a look in the truecrypt docu http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=security-model and it seems you need admin rights to mount truecrypt volumes (at least initially)

Comment: So it isn't possible to just click the unmount button in Nautilus to unmount the TrueCrypt volume? It does work now but when I open TrueCrypt, the volume is still shown mounted.

Comment: doesnt work for me, it still asks for root.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having unmount issues with TrueCrypt, try going to **Settings** > **Preferences** > **System Integration** and check '**Do not use kernel cryptographic services**'.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using your volume and make sure no other program's current working directory is on the volume. Then try:

```
umount -a
```

This will try to unmount all unused filesystems on your computer, including your TrueCrypt volume.